# Submit action changing my routes

Tags: php, zend-framework, submit, routes

I have one form in my page, when i send this form my routes change automatically.

One example:

My normal route: login/attempt

route changed: login/attempt/email_ak/brian.rno%40gmail.com/submit_ak/Enviar

But not is my current route, are the respective links on the page that are changed.

Someone know how i can remove this?

Comment: What do you use to create the url for the action of the form? Please add the code as example.

Comment: Does your form uses GET as method? You could try POST.